# How to get total product sales count for specific product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I need tho get the total number of sold products for specific product from specific date in woocommerece. I tried the following

I tried code.

```
function wh_get_total_sold_by_product_id($date_from, $product_id)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $date_to = date('Y-m-d');

    $sql = "
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS sale_count
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items AS order_items
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta AS order_meta ON order_items.order_item_id = order_meta.order_item_id
    INNER JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts ON order_meta.meta_value = posts.ID
    WHERE order_items.order_item_type = 'line_item'
    AND order_meta.meta_key = '_product_id'
    AND order_meta.meta_value = %d
    AND order_items.order_id IN (
        SELECT posts.ID AS post_id
        FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
        WHERE posts.post_type = 'shop_order'
            AND posts.post_status IN ('wc-completed','wc-processing')
             AND DATE(posts.post_date) BETWEEN %s AND %s
    )
    GROUP BY order_meta.meta_value";

    return $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare($sql, $product_id, $date_from, $date_to));
}
```

Updated

```
   $orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing' ),
    'date_query'  => array(
    'after'   => date('Y-m-d', time() - 86400),
    'before'  => date('Y-m-d', time()+ 86400),
)
) );

$total_sales = 0;
foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {
        $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); 
        $total_sales = $total_sales + get_post_meta( $product_id, 'total_sales', true );
        
    }
}

echo $total_sales;
```

But the function is returning only the total orders not the product count. How can i make it product count. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

WC save total sales of products in post meta with key `total_sales`. try the below code.

```
$total_sales = get_post_meta( $product_id, 'total_sales', true );
```

> Use `date_query` as parameter in `get_posts`. check the below
> code.

```
$orders = get_posts( array(
    'numberposts' => - 1,
    'post_type'   => array( 'shop_order' ),
    'post_status' => array( 'wc-completed', 'wc-processing' ),
    'date_query'  => array(
        'after'   => '2020-05-01',
        'before'  => '2021-05-01',
    )
) );

$total_sales = 0;
foreach ( $orders as $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {
        $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); 
        $total_sales = $total_sales + get_post_meta( $product_id, 'total_sales', true );
    }
}

echo $total_sales;
```

USEFUL LINKS

- [date-parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters)

Comment: how to get the count for specific period?

Comment: Its always returning 0

Comment: No. Its not still returning correct number. I added order for 6 and 2 units from 2 products. Its showing 11 units for all the products.

Comment: From the database i can see this above data points to the total sale of that product for all the time. But i need only sales from specific period. Thanks

Comment: did you pass the dates in the date query?

Comment: do not add code in the comments. update in question.

Comment: after (string/array) – Date to retrieve posts after. Accepts strtotime()-compatible string, or array of ‘year’, ‘month’, ‘day’ values: [read here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#date-parameters)

Comment: I updated data query. Still it is showing all order units from all the time.